# Building a Production Bundle from Aurelia-CLI

Tags: aurelia

Using the Aurelia CLI, I've run `au build --env prod` in order to build a (what I assumed was a) production bundle.

I think copied `index.html` and the `scripts` folder into a web server.

However, I'm recieving the following exception when hitting the web server from the browser:

`vendor-bundle.js:formatted:3912 GET http://ip_address/node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd/aurelia-templating-resources.js 404 (Not Found)`

Why does the Aurelia-CLI's bundle still look for files in `node_modules` from the `vendor-bundle.js`? Isn't the idea that the bundle contains all the necessary files for deployment?

Here is my [`aurelia.json`](https://gist.github.com/fedoranimus/b8e68c56a8211c4c2c891dd85e74e708)

Comment: Maybe just a spelling mistake? the `--` should be before env like so `--env prod` not before prod

Comment: Oops, that's just a mistake on the SO question. I've verified that the bundles are being created and minified.

Answer (score 2):

### Make sure you install and bundle the correct libs

In this case, `aurelia-templating-resources` isn't listed in your `vendor-bundle`.